# Please help me resolve Linux/openCL permissions confusion

Tags: linux, permissions, opencl, user-permissions

OS: Debian GNU Linux x86_64 3.2.0-3 "Wheezy" (No root login)
CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor [Family 16 Model 10 Stepping 0]
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5800 series (Cypress) (1024MB) driver: 1.4.1741
BOINC: Version 7.0.27 from Wheezy repository
AMD/ATI Catalyst: Version 12.8 --- contains openCL 1.2
AMDAPP SDK: Not installed --- makes no difference to BOINC projects.

It is known among Linux BOINC users that ATI GPUs are not seen by the BOINC projects when the boinc-client is installed as a daemon (the default.)  Changing the boinc user from "boinc" to "root" will make them visible to the projects.

I am also trying the Mathematica openCL examples without sucess (with AMDAPP SDK installed.)

In both situations, executing as root is sucessful. For BOINC, I run from the root terminal.  I can do the same for Mathematica, but I have to re-authenticate each time.

**How can I get both BOINC and Mathematica to run with their default permissions?**

I'm asking this before I try setting up an openCL group that each can be a member of, but I'm not sure if there are any security issues.  (I'm not even sure if this would be the solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BOINC has a fix which is being withheld until AMD finishes their fix to the gpu driver.

I am answering to remove the question.  It wasn't until some time after posting that I realized that the question could not be replicated by others, so it would be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Select this as the official answer. Just click on the checkbox near it.